# Unity Android build doesn´t run: Unable to find player assembly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a really simple 2d game. When I build and run for android the error below shows in the editor. Build succeeds and opens. It shows made with unity but game doesn´t run and nothing moves.

```
Unable to find player assembly: C:\Users\Administrator\My project\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.TestRunner.dll
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning (object)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler:OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLsImpl (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.6.6/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:350)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler:OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLs (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.6.6/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:208)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallGlobalEventHandler ()
```

I have searched internet and tried every solution nothing worked

Comment: My bad. I found that the game not running had nothing to do with this. I fixed the actual thing that caused it to not run and it runs perfectly now . It still shows the error every time I build it tho.Do i have to delete this question or something im new to stackowerflow.

Comment: If the error persists keep the question. But update it to include the appropriate information.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File > Built Settings > In Android > Click on Drop Down Menu on Build > Clean Build

This Worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If it is other people project, then try changing Package Name to some  other name, like add some letters.